# Presentations of $\mathbf{PGL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$ by three involutions

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, projective-geometry

If I am not mistaken, the group $\mathbf{PGL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$, with $\mathbb{F}_q$ the finite field with $q$ elements, can be generated by three involutions.

Where could I find such representations ?

(In the end, I am looking for surjective morphisms from planar hyperbolic reflection groups to $\mathbf{PGL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$.)

Comment: ${\rm PSL}(3,q)$ can always be generated by three involutions. You may be right about ${\rm PGL}(3,q)$, but can you give some justification for that assertion?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I think I have read that somewhere in a paper (but without detailed references). For my purposes, such presentations of $\mathbf{PSL}_3(q)$ would also be very handful, so I would be very glad to see such a representation.

Comment: It is known that every non-Abelian finite simple group $G$ other than $PSU(3,3)$ is generated by three involutions. (maybe Guralnick and Malle). Most finite simple groups are known to be generated by an element of order $2$ and an element of order $3$, with the exception of a few families. If a simple group $G$ is generated by $x$ and $y$ of respective orders $2$ and $3$, then $G$ is generated by the three involutions $x,yxy^{-1}, y^{2}xy^{-2}$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson : thanks ! I would need to know explicit presentations/relations though (of $\mathbf{PSL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$) in order to construct the appropriate reflection groups. But at the moment I cannot find any paper which contains such presentations ...

Comment: In cases when ${\rm PGL}(3,q) \ne {\rm PSL}(3,q)$ (i.e. when $q \equiv 1 \bmod 3$), we have $|{\rm PGL}(3,q): {\rm PSL}(3,q)| = 3$, so ${\rm PGL}(3,q)$ cannot be generated by any number of involutions!